# The probability distribution of a discrete random variable $X$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$f_X(x)=\dfrac{5x+k}{65}$ for $x=0,1,2,3,4$ is the probability mass function.

What is the value of $k$?
What is the standard deviation of $X$?

I get $k=0$, but I don't think it's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(0)= \frac{k}{65}$

$f(1)= \frac{5+ k}{65}$

$f(2)= \frac{10+ k}{65}$

$f(3)= \frac{15+ k}{65}$

$f(4)= \frac{20+ k}{65}$.

Since those are the only possible values for x, the "total probability" must be 1.
That is $\frac{k}{65}+ \frac{5+k}{65}+ \frac{10+ k}{65}+ \frac{15+ k}{65}+ \frac{20+ k}{65}= \frac{50+ 5k}{65}= 1$.  Solve that for k.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac 5 {65} (0+1+2+3+4) +\frac {5k} {65}=1$ and this gives $k=3$.